# What's an example of some invalid markdown?

Tags: unit-testing, markdown

I'm writing unit tests for a model with an attribute that's interpreted as markdown.  I'd like to test that if the markdown is invalid, then the object is invalid - but it's such a forgiving syntax that everything I've tried so far turns out to be valid markdown!  What's an example of some invalid markdown?

Comment: Great question! I wrote a test for invalid Markdown only to find this post when I started looking for examples… What I ended up doing was one test that assumes there are broken links if the rendered HTML contains "[" or "]". Should work for my use case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't used markdown extensively but i was under the impression that it is impossible to write "invalid" markdown only markdown that wont do what you want it to. As in instead of throwing an error when it doesn't know what to do it just treats it as plain text.

On a different path one could probably write a script to try and identify things that the user probably didn't intend, for example if someone entered `**test*` they probably intended `*test*` or `**test**`

Comment: Agreed; any text is "valid" markdown - but the result is sometimes not what the user expects. That's the difference between a Wiki-like language and, say, XML.

Answer (score 4):

All strings are valid markdown.

Answer (score 2):

If all text is markdown and vice versa, then I suppose one example of invalid markdown would be invalid text in the encoding that you are using, i.e. invalid UTF-8, invalid ASCII or invalid ISO-8859-1.