# Markdown syntax checking for continous integration?

Tags: continuous-integration, markdown

Short story: I'm using Markdown to write a novel. [Long story is here](https://medium.com/i-m-h-o/five-reasons-why-writing-is-so-much-like-software-development-6d154a43719c). In [this site](https://github.com/JJ/nyc-42-8) I typo-check the text using a Perl module (which I also developed), but I'd like to check MD syntax too. However, most markdown tool seem to be too lenient on errors, letting go stuff like this

```
This is an *error
This would be [another error](
```

Besides, there is no "check-only" option that returns false when there's an error, so that it can be used in continuous integration tests. The only one that balks out in this stuff is maruku. Kramdown, pandoc, marked, markdown (for nodejs), all of them let it go without a glitch.
Question is, is there a markdown syntax validator or checker in any language I can use easily in CI? Or should I go with maruku, despite being considered obsolete by his authors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5521857/214446), "it is impossible to write "invalid" markdown only markdown that wont do what you want it to." Every string is valid markdown.

You could, however define a subset of markdown that excludes markdown like the examples you mentioned in the question, and modify an existing parser to adhere to that subset.

Comment: In fact, GitHub pages throw an error if they find that kind of things. GH-Pages uses jekyll which relies in a number of markdown parsers, including maruku. I was wondering which one they were actually using and using which options, but I couldn't find them...

Comment: @jjmerelo interesting. Since July 30, [GitHub Pages uses Kramdown as the default markdown engine](https://github.com/blog/1867-github-pages-now-runs-jekyll-2-2-0)

Comment: It does mention "better error handling". I'll check it. Thanks!